# Why is this multithreaded C program giving me segmentation fault?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

My intention is to transpose two files using multithreading. But the program below is giving me segmentation fault.

```
#include   <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include  <string.h>


void *a_to_temp( void *filea);
void copyFile( FILE *in, FILE *out );
void *temp_to_b( void *fileb);
void *b_to_a(void *ab);

struct files{
    char a[80];
    char b[80];
} ab;

pthread_mutex_t temptob     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t btoa        = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "in main");

    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;
    strcpy( ab.a, argv[1]);
    strcpy(ab.b, argv[2]);

    int  iret1, iret2, iret3;

    pthread_mutex_lock( &temptob );
    pthread_mutex_lock( &btoa );

    iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, a_to_temp, (void*) &argv[1]);

    iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, b_to_a, (void*) &ab);

    iret3 = pthread_create( &thread3, NULL, temp_to_b, (void*) &argv[2]);


    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join( thread3, NULL);

    exit(0);
}


void *a_to_temp( void *filea) {
    FILE *a = fopen((char *)filea, "r");    
    FILE *f = fopen( "temp", "w");
    copyFile( a , f);
    fclose(f);
    fclose( a); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &temptob );
}

void *temp_to_b( void *fileb) {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &temptob );
    FILE *b = fopen((char *)fileb, "r");
    FILE *f = fopen( "temp", "r");
    copyFile( f, b);
    fclose(f);  
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &btoa );
}

void *b_to_a(void *ab) {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &btoa );
    FILE *a = fopen(((struct files *) ab)->a, "w"); //
    FILE *b = fopen(((struct files *) ab)->b, "r");//
    fprintf(stderr, "c files opened");
    copyFile( b, a);
    fclose(a);
    fclose(b);
}

void copyFile( FILE *in, FILE *out) {
    char ch;
    while(!feof(in)) {
        ch = getc(in);  
        if(!feof(in)) putc(ch, out);            
    }
}
```

I've tested the code until the end of the main function by printing values. I'm guessing that the error should be inside one of the functions.

Comment: Only a thread that owns a lock is allowed to unlock it.

Comment: You don't close both files in `temp_to_b`. But that's not your problem. Why are you using threads to do this when you then proceed to attempt to serialise the three threads? What could you achieve by doing that? Why are you not checking for errors in any of your code. Always check for runtime errors. Otherwise you are wearing a blindfold. And why are you copy contents of the files rather than just trivially renaming the files. Do it with a rename operation and  the program will run instantly and take around 10 lines to write!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's a homework exercise for to familiarize people with the threads and issues surrounding threads.  There could be a performance benefit to having the copies run in parallel.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's a dumb assignment I'm forced to do. I didn't have the time to read the documentation well. Can you point me to where I can learn how to serialize the threads?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The copies can't safely run in parallel. Hence the attempts in the code to serialize.

Comment: @tbert I posted the question only because I thought there must be some logic problem.

Comment: @user25464 A lock is the wrong sync object here. You probably want to use a condition variable. And yes, it's a pretty dumb assignment. One word of advice. If you tell us that it's a dumb assignment, then we can ignore that when commenting/answering. And tell us what the goal of the assignment is. In this case what you need to know is that mutexes/locks are the wrong solution. But the question you asked is why you have seg fault.

Comment: That's because the implementation of the algorithm is broken.  It should be doing 'copy A to temp1; copy B to temp2; synchronize; copy temp1 to B; copy temp2 to A; drop temp1; drop temp2' if 'transpose two files' means 'swap contents of the two files'.  Alternatively, as with swapping variables, you can do 'copy A to temp; copy B to A; copy temp to B'.  If you have multiple disk drives, then the two temp files might get you some parallelism at the disk level; otherwise, your pretty much sequentially I/O bound.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If you have only one disk drive then that will be even  slower than the single temp file problem. But yes, it is an assignment and we are getting very off topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `&argv[1]` to the `a_to_temp()` function, which is a `char **`, and then try to use it as if it was a `char *`.  Ditto for `&argv[2]` and the `temp_to_b()` function.  This is not a recipe for happiness; a core dump is quite a plausible response.

The simplest fix is to drop the `&` in the `pthread_create()` calls.  The alternative is to handle the `char **` in the called functions.

Note: this simply fixes the core dumps caused by accessing the wrong data.  There may be algorithmic problems with the code too, ensuring that the correct synchronization occurs.  And it is debatable whether there is any performance gain to using threads here.  Indeed, there probably isn't.  But that is presumably tangential to the point of the exercise, which is to get threaded code working at all.

---

> Can you enlighten me how to serialize my threads. I was trying to use mutexes which don't seem to help.

One item would be to ensure you error check every system call; at the moment, you are assuming everything will work.  However, I think [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236222/jay) is on the right track with 'the thread that locks a mutex must unlock it too'.  You probably want one or two conditions ([`pthread_cond_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_init.html) et al) controlling access to the files instead of the mutexes.

Comment: Can you enlighten me how to serialize my threads. I was trying to use mutexes which don't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

One problem with your code is that you are locking the mutex in one thread and unlocking it in another thread which is not allowed.

If you try to unlock a mutex in a thread which doesn't own it, it can result in undefined behavior.

For instance your `pthread_mutex_lock( &temptob );` is in main thread whereas `pthread_mutex_unlock( &temptob );` is in a_to_temp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you tell me how I make the threads run sequentially?

Comment: @user25464: you could use a semaphore with an initial count of 1 to imitate a lock that can be "unlocked" (posted) in a different thread from the one it was "locked" (waited). But it looks as though you want thread A to run, then B, then C. The proper way to do that is to join A before creating B. Serializing the work has made the threads basically pointless, so you might need to look again at what this assignment is trying to teach you.

Comment: @SteveJessop my professor wants us to make the threads communicate so that they run in sequential manner and don't write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: @user25464: OK, semaphores and condition variables provide two ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to intervene, but it is my impression that what you really want to achieve is not necessarily mutual exclusion, but rather serialization of the operations (ie: *ordering* the operations: first: copy_a_to_temp; second: copy_b_to_a; third: copy_temp_to_b). The above answers are right about locking and unlocking mutexes by the same thread. However, for ordering (or, more exactly, forcing a thread to *wait* until another one accomplished a task) is not really a job of mutexes, but rather a job of monitors/condition variables (or, in a more complicated way, of a semaphore, since a semaphore can implement a monitor). To force a thread (for example, copy_b_to_a must *not* occur before copy_a_to_temp completed its work), you should use pthread_cond_wait. See this question for a question exposing how to use pthread_cond_wait: [Am I forced to use pthread_cond_broadcast (over pthread_cond_signal) in order to guarantee that *my* thread is woken up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10868946/1284631)

Comment: I should add that my first try to *wait* for another thread was just like yours: trying to acquire two successive times the same mutex, that another thread should have unlock somewhere between the two successive locks. It was, however, the wrong strategy.